# counting up a table to summarize the count of instances

Tags: sql

Could use some help please. I have a table with user info and I need to create a report that shows a summary of the count of each state where status is complete.

Data in DB - there is more but this is what I need to keep track of.

```
status |State 
open |  New York
closed | Florida
open | New York 
open | California
open New York
```

Output should say:

```
State   Count

New York  3
California 1
```

Can someone be so kind to help me with what the query looks like?

Comment: GROUP BY combined with aggregate function count!

Comment: Although most probably not relevant for this question, you should still always add a tag for the DBMS you are using (`postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, ...)

Answer (score 0):

this should help.

```
select state, count(*) from tablename where Status= 'open'
Group by state
```

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
select
  state, count(status) cnt
from tbl
where status  = 'open'
group by state
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
SELECT state, count(status) FROM table WHERE status = 'open' GROUP BY  state
```